# How to uninstall module if admin/modules path is not accessible due to memory error

Tags: 7, installation

The problem is - I installed ubercart and was playing with devel module. Now when I'm trying to go to admin/modules I'm getting:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 8642561 bytes)

I would like to uninstall devel module because I think this is its fault, but I can't as I don't have access to admin/modules because of this error :/ . Is there another way to uninstall a module and free some memory?

**Edit:** Well, turning off some options in devel settings helped, but still it would be nice to know answer to this question as problem can potentially appear for someone :) .

Comment: Related: [White screen of death: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of X bytes exhausted](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/54239/1908)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use [drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush):

`drush dis MODULE-NAME`

- You can also disable modules manually in the database:

`UPDATE system SET status='0' WHERE name='module_name';`

Then you need to clear cached system list (Drupal 7 only):

`DELETE FROM cache_bootstrap WHERE cid='system_list'`

Comment: Just to add for emergent situations, removing the module (or the theme) folder out of the sites/all/modules will always disable it and then you can access the site.